# How to write the full path to a cifs share on the command line

Tags: networking, cifs

I have mounted a cifs share on my network, and I want to create a symlink to a document on that share.  The share is created like this:

sudo mount -t cifs -o username=(username),password=(password),dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 "//192.168.0.2/D Share" /mnt/smb_share

Now I can see the share on the “Other Locations” section of Nautilus in mnt/smb_share.

To create a symbolic link:  ln [source], [reference].  But how do I write the path to the source?  I tried first to list the contents of the folder:

```
ls mnt/smb_share/Project Backups/

ls: cannot access 'mnt/smb_share/Project': No such file or directory

ls: cannot access 'Backups/': No such file or directory
```

If I put it in quotes (ls "mnt/smb_share/Project Backups/") I just get a command prompt.  Nautilus doesn’t allow me to copy it from the breadcrumbs, and neither does Libre Office.

When I research this, I get a lot of hits for how to create the share, but my question is different.

How do I write the full path to the cifs share for the command line?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 things going on here:

1. `mnt` is a *relative path* (relative to the directory you're in when you issue the `ls` command). If you're not in `/`, then you need to prepend the `/` to make it an *absolute path* <sup>1</sup>
2. you need to either quote (as you tried) or escape the space.

So

```
ls "/mnt/smb_share/Project Backups/"
```

or

```
ls /mnt/smb_share/Project\ Backups/
```

---

1. or construct a correct relative path by going up the directory tree like `../../mnt`